# Does the Archery skill only level up when hitting NPCs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Will my Archery go up when shooting targets and dummies, or only on NPCs?

Comment: "Will my Archery go up when shooting targets and dummies" here: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23698/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only levels up when you do damage ([source](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archery)).

Hits don't count.